# Accessing desktop equivalent viewport size while on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I've got a function which exports a React component to a PDF, which is as follows:

```
const exportToPdf = () => {

        const input = document.getElementById(active)

        if (input != null) {

            html2canvas(input, {
                scale: 5
            })
            .then((canvas) => {
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 2.0)
                
                const componentWidth = canvas.offsetWidth
                const componentHeight = canvas.offsetHeight 

                const orientation = componentWidth >= componentHeight ? 'l' : 'p'

                const pdf = new jsPDF({
                    orientation,
                    unit: "px"
                })

                pdf.internal.pageSize.width = width
                pdf.internal.pageSize.height = height

                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height)
                pdf.save(`${name}.pdf`)

            })
            .then(() => {
                setDisplay(false)
            })
        }
    }
```

To determine the height / width of the PDF export, it takes the width / height of the component, which is stored as state and set in a useEffect:

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(modernTemplate.current.clientHeight)
    setWidth(modernTemplate.current.clientWidth)
        
}, [active])
```

To do this, I use the useRef hook.

However, with this approach, it means that if a user is viewing the page on mobile, that the component measurements are calculated with a mobile viewport.

What I want to do instead is set the height / width to be what it is on a desktop device, while on a mobile device.

Is there a way for me to refactor my code to access what the clientHeight / clientWidth would be while looking on a desktop device?

Comment: Why don't you set the height/width yourself based on an A4 size? Like 816x1056 max

Comment: The height is dynamic unfortunately - I could set a consistent width, but the height is always the same.